# Как открыть окно chrome JavaScript (с закладками и контролами)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Этот код откроет страничку в новом окне :

```
javascript:(function() {
window.open('https://example.com', '', 'menubar=yes,location=yes,status=yes,channelmode=yes,toolbar=yes,resizable=yes');

})();
```

Но откроется только сайт без кнопок назад-вперёд-обновить, и без закладок, и без панели вкладок. Как открыть окно вместе со всем этим?

Comment: Ты возможно когда-то (когда у тебя наверное Adguard не стоял) напарывался на рекламу с popup'ами в новом окне. Вероятно как ты видел, большинство людей не заморачиваются по этому поводу и просто делают так как сделал сейчас ты, т.е. там тоже не было панели закладок, и любых других органов управления браузером кроме кнопок "закрыть","свернуть" и "полный экран".

Comment: @EugenEray ну да, а как сделать то чтобы они были? .___.